# Taking the dot product of a np.ndarray in Python

Tags: python, numpy

[image]

I am trying to find the value of the dot product of x, which is 1.17794933^2 + (-0.07446217)^2 = 1.3931. I tried `x.dot(x)` but that did not seem to work. Is there another way to perform dot product when `x` is of type `numpy.ndarray`?

Comment: Pay attention to the `shape` of your array, and read the docs!.   `x.dot(x.T)` or `x.T.dot(x)` should work, where `.T` produces the transpose.  Read, and reread if necessary, the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your desired output, You may try `einsum`

```
In [1254]: np.einsum('ij,ij',x,x)
Out[1254]: 1.3931092388085575
```